# Google cloud endpoints framework not compatible with Android studio and gradle 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I recently updated Android studio to version 3.4 and with it came a gradle update (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0) and with that came gradle 5.1.1-all.zip.

When attempting to sync gradle with the project, the result is:

> ERROR: Unable to find method
>   'org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;'

This traces back to the gradle plugin:

> 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

which is required in order to use the google cloud endpoints framework.

I was curious if anyone else has experienced this and if they have found a solution or if this is out of my control and a bug report needs to be filed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, the solution was to update the endpoint framework gradle plugin to v2.0.1

"com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:2.0.1"

on both the app and backend gradle files.